# Adding UIButton to AVPlayer in iOS (Swift) When Video Plays in WebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uibutton, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm putting together an iOS app (using Swift) that contains a webview. A user will click on a video in the webview and the video will load, at which time I want to display a button on the video. I've been able to display the button but it is not responding to touches and I'm not sure why. I made the button huge just to make sure it was being hit. Here's my code. I extended AVPlayerViewController.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {

    open override func viewDidLoad() {

        let btn = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        btn.setTitle("Do stuff", for: .normal)
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 330, width: 300, height: 300)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.isEnabled = true
        btn.clipsToBounds = true

        self.contentOverlayView?.addSubview((btn as? UIButton)!)
        self.showsPlaybackControls = false


    }


    func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
        print("Worked")
    }

}
```

[image: Screen Shot of iOS App]

Comment: Did you find the fix?

Answer (score 1):

In your extension of `AVPlayerViewController`, you have overridden viewDidLoad method, which is not correct in my view. Instead you can add the button adding logic in the extension and call that method eherever ypu have initialized the `AVPlayerViewController`.

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {
func addButton() {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    btn.setTitle("Do stuff", for: .normal)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 330, width: 300, height: 300)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    btn.isEnabled = true
    btn.clipsToBounds = true

    self.contentOverlayView?.addSubview((btn as? UIButton)!)
    self.showsPlaybackControls = false
}

func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
    print("Worked")
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Also, I don't need to instantiate an AVPlayerViewController anywhere. The user clicks the video link in the webview and the video begins playing. As far as I know, you cannot add a custom video player to webview.